# Durock cement board on exterior foundation

Tags: foundation

So I'm trying to figure out what to do to finish my exterior foundation.  The rim joist for the house is on top of concrete blocks.  The issue is the grading around my house isn't consistent.  The back of the house the ground is about 6" from my rim joist and towards the front of the house it's about 3 feet.

There is dimplex/dimpled foundation wrap in front of the concrete blocks, but since the grade around our house isnt consistent it is exposed in the front of our house, and below grade in the back of the house.

This past fall I installed Blueskin on the foundation exterior from on top of the exposed rim joist, over the exposed concrete blocks to "tie in it" to the dimpled foundation wrap as a waterproofing membrane.  I painted it with acrylic paint to try and stop uv rays destorying the Blueskin.

Now I'm looking to parge the foundation to cover up the Blueskin and make everything look better.  I've heard that cement/parging won't bond to Blueskin...

My question for you fine people - can I attach durock cement board on top of the Blueskin, scotchred the cement board to help waterproof it and then parge over the cement board?  The cement board would go about 4" below grade and right to the top of the rim joist where my siding (wood) starts.

Comment: Include "EIFS" in your internet searches.

Comment: what does scotchred the cement board mean?

Comment: I'm wondering if that's some kind of Redgard or something.  The only "scotchred" I know of is Johnny Walker.

Comment: I presume it's (needless) additional waterproofing, probably misnomering reguard. if the "blueskin" material is waterproof, the cementboard would not need to be waterproofed. And indeed, using foamboard insulation with stucco over (Exterior Insulating and Finishing System - EIFS) would probably be a better use of money for a similar-looking (but better insulated) result.